# Filter/order django rest api on a property=value but property is a value instead of a field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Consider an object that has multiple properties.

```py
class Object(models.Model):
    name= Charfield(max_length=80)

class Property(models.Model):
    object= ForeignKey(Object, related_name='properties')
    name= Charfield(max_length=80)
    value= Charfield(max_length=80)
```

I would like to provide an api accessible listview for the Object model, but I'm failing at ordering the ObjectList by property value as well as at sorting the the ObjectList by property value.

To make the example more tangible you can imagine that Object has as type book, and an object of book has, among other properties, a property with name `title` and a value such as `20,000 Leagues Under the Sea`. I would like to be able to be able to specify `?order_by=title` and to be able to filter `?title__contains=League` (or at least `?title="20,000 Leagues Under the Sea"`.

I already did try to annotate Object with `title="20,000 Leagues Under the Sea"` and I'm able to show the title in the ObjectSerializer as if it was a field, but then ordering by this field does not work.

Comment: can you provide example of your viewset here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks like a standard [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model.

You might consider looking at a package like [django-eav2](https://django-eav-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and see if that helps somewhat.  I don't think it handles ordering, which is sensible since its actually difficult to do through an ORM.

Have you considered changing your model to either use a JSON column or HStore (if you are on postgres)?  Depending on your data model they could work perfectly and are also easily indexed, searched, and ordered by.

If you want to do it yourself, there are a few things you'll need to write:

- Helper functions to filter & order by fields in the attributes table
- Custom `OrderingBackend` implementation
- Custom `FilterField` to handle filtering by an attribute
- Custom `DjangoFilterBackend` depending on how you want the urls to behave

If you can provide a better example of what you'd like the URL to look like then it'll be easier to help give some guidance.  Since your attributes can have any name, you have some choices to make:

1. Is the url parameter the attribute name (e.g. ?title=)
2. Do you use a custom url format, like `?attr=title&value=The Big Bang`
3. Do you need to filter on the `Object` level?
4. Can you filter / order by more than one thing at a time?
5. How do you handle different data types (date/int/string/etc?)

Sorry, but this is just too big a question for a single answer here.  Though it is possible if you try hard enough, building EAV queries is not easy and they are *not* fast.

Comment: Hi, the custom url format you proposed was key for me to figure out how to solve the problem on an api level. I was able to use the `attr=title` to annotate the queryset and afterwards I could use value in all the existing OrderingBackends and Filterfields. 
The link to EAV was also useful! It helped me improve and document some of the design choices I had to make!

Answer (score 4):

Consider what you are trying to accomplish and how it maps to SQL queries (using ORM is convenient, but you have to always keep in mind that all your ORM calls get translated into SQL). You have a table `books` and you have a table `properties`. Lets say

```
create table books (
    id integer primary key,
);

create table properties (
    id integer primary key,
    name text,
    value text,
    book_id integer,
)
```

And then you insert records like this

```
insert into books set (id) values (1);
insert into properties set (id, name, value, book_id) values (1, 'title', 'A Book', 1)
```

And then you want to pull books and titles, so you end up with something like this

```
select b.id, p.value as "title"
from books as b
join properties as p on (b.id = p.book_id)
where p.name = 'title'
order by p.value
```

Unfortunately, building the query above using the ORM is not trivial. The reason for that is that by introducing both the name of the property and the value as data instead of writing data into a specific field, you are subverting your ability to refer to specific properties. You cannot simply refer to the book title as a specific field because it is not a field. What if the book has no 'title' property record? What if it has more than one?

You can do what you want using the Subquery() function from the ORM API, but I have never personally used it, so I am not sure what the exact syntax for that would be. Probably something like this

```
title = Property.objects.filter(name='title', book_id=OuterRef('pk')).values('value')[:1]
books = Object.objects.annotate(title=Subquery(title)).order_by('title')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

That said, this is fragile and hard to reason about and you might want to reconsider your database architecture.

Comment: Hi, I was using subquery indeed in my search for a solution. I arrived at a similar conclusion as you. Can you elaborate how this is fragile?

Comment: If you have a field, like title, and write queries against it you can be very sure that at the very least the field exists and contains a value. The value might be null if your constraints allow it, but it will be a value. In your case, you are not guaranteed that the field exists at all. You can setup constraints that would prevent multiple titles, but you cannot enforce a book to have a title. So now you have to be extra careful about your queries, using the right type of joins etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following models:

```py
class Object(models.Model):
    name= Charfield(max_length=80)

class Property(models.Model):
    object= ForeignKey(Object, related_name='properties')
    name= Charfield(max_length=80)
    value= Charfield(max_length=80)
```

then you have instances of `Object` having only one property, with `name='title'`.

In this setting, I would go with something like:

```py
Object.objects.filter(
    properties__name=Value('title'), 
    properties__value__icontains=request.data['title']
    )
```

for filtering.

Regarding ordering, you'll hit an other issue: you attempt to order by a field of a Many2One relationship (many properties for one object), but only on one of the related objects in this relation... Subqueries as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58066020/8635939) might be the way to go, but I have personally already tried to do that without success.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58064495/8635939) precises that your structure is hard to handle. Indeed, in your case, assuming you add at some point the authors of your books as `Object` instance, these objects will not have the `title` property at all...

If you cannot forgo this db architecture, I would advise looking into [JSON fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) or [HStore fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield). DjangoORM provides ways to query these fields according to what you try to achieve. However, be aware that this will still be slower than using a tradition architecture for RDBMSs.

Otherwise, create a 'real' `Book` model, that has a title, and in this case, everything is much simpler ;)

EDIT: also you have the possibility to write your query directly in SQL, either executed from a `cursor` directly (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)) or from a queryset of the model (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)). I've used both approaches in various scenarios, you'll have to be careful with how you handle user input, but it should work =)

Comment: The 'Book' model was perhaps not a bad example, but there are other reasons to chose for the other architecture. The properties are a bit complexer than fields since we want to allow the user to design properties themselves.  JSON and HStore are also not ideal, since I need the fields to be separate object, with links to meta-fields and multiple tests. Which is harder to do with alternative architectures.

Comment: From what I understand of your use-case, I would personally choose to do the filtering/ordering manually in SQL. I resorted to this for my own stuff, where I use full-text search on several fields depending on whether the user provided an input for searching in the field... If you're not afraid of SQL, that might be the most straight-forward solution

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine method `get_queryset()` that prepares query to database and can do sorting for you by field(-s) you provide.
Have a look to example that I provided. Not sure if it works out-of-the box, but hope that you understood the logic. But if you'll have questions - please add comment.

```py
class ObjectViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ObjectViewSet, self).get_queryset()

        order_by = self.request.query_params.get('order_by', '')
        if order_by:
            order_by_name = order_by.split(' ')[1]
            order_by_sign = order_by.split(' ')[0]
            order_by_sign = '' if order_by_sign == 'asc' else '-'
            queryset = queryset.order_by(order_by_sign + order_by_name)

        return queryset
```

Comment: @Pinna_be, it will be easier to help you if you'll provide your example of view or viewset you use.

Comment: Hi, this is not an ideal way to handle this in djangorestframework, since you lose all functtionality provided by https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter.